# Opencv: how to set a complete row of pixels?

Tags: opencv

I'm new to opencv so I'm experimenting to learn the basic concepts.

So I started with a simple mat, and tried to set the middle row to some value.

I expected the entire row to be displayed the same, but only the first half of the row is white.

[image]

```
 #define SWIDTH  12
 #define SHEIGHT 12

Mat m = Mat::zeros(SWIDTH, SHEIGHT, CV_16U);

for (int x=0;x<SWIDTH;x++)
    m.at<unsigned char>(SHEIGHT/2,x) = 65000;

cv::Size size(512, 512);
Mat mResized;
cv::resize(m, mResized, size,0,0,INTER_NEAREST );

cv::imshow("mResized", mResized);
cv::imshow("m", m);
```

So why is only half the row set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix seems to be unsigned short datatype, doesn't that mean you need to use:

```
m.at<unsigned short>(SHEIGHT/2,x) = 65000;
```

instead of `unsigned char`, this could explain why you are filling half of the row only.

Comment: Thanks, rookie mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [row](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-row), to set all pixels in the row without using the for loop:

```
m.row(SHEIGHT/2) = 65000
```